# Passed when the function is not finished

Tags: javascript, protractor

So I have been working with protractor about passing/failing tests and I have created a amout of clicks to be done in the script. Basically that to run x amout of clicks and once it is finished then it should pass.

NEW EDIT

```
it('Click remove button', function (done) {

    let allProds = element.all(by.css('div.stock-controller'));

    allProds.count()
    .then(function (cnt) { // amount of products

        let allPromises = []

        for(let index=0;index<cnt;index++) {

            let section = allProds.get(index),

                // message string which include qty in stock
                stock_qty_str = section.element(by.css('div.message')).getText(),
                // user inputed qty 
                user_qty_str = section.element(by.css('div.quantity-input input'))
                                      .getAttribute('value'),
                // button Descrease
                btn_dec = section.element(by.css('button[aria-label="Decrease"]'));

            allPromises.push(Promise.all([stock_qty_str, user_qty_str])
                .then(function(data){
                    // use RegExp to extract qty in stock
                    let group = data[0].trim().match(/^Sorry.*?(\d+)/)

                    if(group) {
                        let stock_qty = group[1] * 1,
                            user_qty = data[1].trim() * 1,
                            gap = user_qty - stock_qty; // click times of Decrease button

                        for(let i=0;i<gap;i++) {
                            btn_dec.click();
                            browser.sleep(1000).then(function(){
                                console.log('Click Decrease button: ' + i + '/' + gap)
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
            )

        }
        return Promise.all(allPromises)

    })
    .then(()=>{
        done();
    })

});
```

However my problem is that what it does now is that:

[image]

as you can see what happens is that it counts how many times it is supposed to click and then marks it as finished but yet it still clicks after the passed which is odd I would say...

I wonder how can I make it wait until the function is fully done and then mark it as passed/failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a promise so the test waits for that promise.

At the moment, the promise returns right away without waiting for the clicks.

You need to gather all `Promise.all` from the for and return that as a promise (using `Promise.all` again probably)

Something like this

```
it('Click remove button', function (done) {

 let allProds = element.all(by.css('div.stock-controller'));

 allProds.count()
 .then(function (cnt) { // amount of products
    let allPromises = []
    for(let index=0;index<cnt;index++) {

        let section = allProds.get(index),

            // message string which include qty in stock
            stock_qty_str = section.element(by.css('div.message')).getText(),
            // user inputed qty 
            user_qty_str = section.element(by.css('div.quantity-input input'))
                                  .getAttribute('value'),
            // button Descrease
            btn_dec = section.element(by.css('button[aria-label="Decrease"]'));

            allPromises.push(Promise.all([stock_qty_str, user_qty_str])...)
     }

     return Promise.all(allPromises)
  })
  .then(()=>{
    done();
  })

});
```

Comment: Hmm im not sure how I am able to do that? and I am not quite sure if I understood it correctly, is there any code example you could provide me where I can see in a way what you mean?

Comment: I have just updated the code to have it like your but the same problem. It still says its passed even thought it clicks. Exactly same issue as previously.

Comment: Just noticed that you have another promise that you don't wait for. browser.sleep(1000).then(...). You need to gather all those promises and return them also.

Comment: I used `.then(async function (data) {` instead of `.then(function (data){` which waits for the browser wait if I do await browser.sleep